# How to use nginfinite-scroll to work on an element?

Tags: angularjs, infinite-scroll

I have got a number of components/windows (divs) on my html page; each div meant to show a large amount of data. Am trying to use nginfinite-scroll (http://binarymuse.github.io/ngInfiniteScroll/documentation.html) on each of these components so that infinite scrolling happens inside each of them. But looks like the infinite-scrolling is triggered only when an element on which the nginfinite-scroll is called nears the end of the browser-window. But i can't have my components move. How do i get infinite scroll happen in-place, i mean inside each component/element whose position would not near the browser end? Hope, the problem statement is understood.
Here's my html:

```
        <div id="myDiv">
        <ul class="list" infinite-scroll='nextPage()'  infinite-scroll-disabled="false">
            <li  data-ng-repeat="item in items">
               <span>{{item}}</span>
            </li>
        </ul>
        </div>
```

Regards

Comment: I also badly need to do the same.